# R: Change column name based on string in row value

Tags: r, dplyr

I have this df that comes from a massive csv file. The current column names have placeholders for their names. Is there a way to make the name of each column the sting part of the data. The string will be the same for the entire column going down. I would change the names manually, but there are 256 columns.

Starting df:

```
   col2          col3       col4     ...
1 version=1    numCh=10   reserved=0
2 version=1    numCh=10   reserved=0
3 version=1    numCh=11   reserved=0
4 version=1    numCh=11   reserved=0
...
```

The desired output:

```
  version    numCh    reserved   ...
1    1        10        0
2    1        10        0
3    1        11        0
4    1        11        0
...
```

Been trying different methods and seeing if anybody else has created something like this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Extract the first row, and remove the substring from `=` with `trimws`, then loop `across` the columns, extract the numeric part with `parse_number` and set the column names with the substring of first row

```
library(dplyr)
 v1 <- trimws(unlist(df1[1,]), whitespace = "=.*")
df1 %>% 
    mutate(across(everything(), readr::parse_number)) %>% 
     setNames(v1)
```

-output

```
  version numCh reserved
1       1    10        0
2       1    10        0
3       1    11        0
4       1    11        0
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(col2 = c("version=1", "version=1", "version=1", 
"version=1"), col3 = c("numCh=10", "numCh=10", "numCh=11", "numCh=11"
), col4 = c("reserved=0", "reserved=0", "reserved=0", "reserved=0"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4"))
```

Answer (score 2):

Or with `base`:

```r
colnames(df) <- trimws(df[1, ], whitespace = "=.*")
df[] <- lapply(df, \(x) as.numeric(trimws(x, whitespace = ".*=")))
```

Output:

```
  version numCh reserved
1       1    10        0
2       1    10        0
3       1    11        0
4       1    11        0
```

Data:

```r
df <- read.table(text = "col2 col3 col4
version=1 numCh=10 reserved=0
version=1 numCh=10 reserved=0
version=1 numCh=11 reserved=0
version=1 numCh=11 reserved=0", header = TRUE)
```

Comment: This works as well. There were some values that were not numbers but changing the **as.numeric** to **as.character** fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative approach:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df1 %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(), ~str_extract(., '[0-9]+')))
```

```
  col2 col3 col4
1    1   10    0
2    1   10    0
3    1   11    0
4    1   11    0
```